# How to run icinga with a apache vHost?

Tags: apache-2.2, debian-squeeze, virtualhost, icinga

I have installed icinga from the icinga own repos on my debian squeeze box but now I don't know how to change the current config:

```
# apache configuration for icinga

  ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/icinga /usr/lib/cgi-bin/icinga
  ScriptAlias /icinga/cgi-bin /usr/lib/cgi-bin/icinga

# Where the stylesheets (config files) reside
  Alias /icinga/stylesheets /etc/icinga/stylesheets

# Where the HTML pages live
  Alias /icinga /usr/share/icinga/htdocs

    <DirectoryMatch (/usr/share/icinga/htdocs|/usr/lib/cgi-   bin/icinga|/etc/icinga/stylesheets)>
      Options FollowSymLinks

      DirectoryIndex index.html

      AllowOverride AuthConfig
      #Order Deny, Allow
      Deny from all
      #Allow From 10.42.0.0/24

      AuthName "Icinga Access"
      AuthType Basic
      AuthUserFile /etc/icinga/htpasswd.users
      require valid-user
    </DirectoryMatch>
```

I want to run icinga under the subdomain monitoring.mysite.com but I fail to make this config a working vHost config. Is there anybody out who can say what I have to change?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because there is no VirtualHost, ServerName or DocumentRoot directives?

Replace the asterisk with IP depending on your configuration, however, the asterisk is standard procedure.

```
# apache configuration for icinga
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName monitoring.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/icinga/htdocs

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/icinga /usr/lib/cgi-bin/icinga
    ScriptAlias /icinga/cgi-bin /usr/lib/cgi-bin/icinga

    # Where the stylesheets (config files) reside
    Alias /icinga/stylesheets /etc/icinga/stylesheets

    # Where the HTML pages live
    Alias /icinga /usr/share/icinga/htdocs

    <DirectoryMatch (/usr/share/icinga/htdocs|/usr/lib/cgi-bin/icinga|/etc/icinga/stylesheets)>
        Options FollowSymLinks

        DirectoryIndex index.html

        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Order Deny, Allow
        #Deny from All
        #Allow From 10.42.0.0/24

        AuthName "Icinga Access"
        AuthType Basic
        AuthUserFile /etc/icinga/htpasswd.users
        Require valid-user
    </DirectoryMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```