# Setting up apache vhost for Icinga

Tags: apache-2.2, monitoring, icinga

It's been a while since I've worked with Apache so please be kind - I'm also aware of [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/356690/how-to-run-icinga-with-a-apache-vhost) but it hasn't been much help to me.

I'd like to set up a simple vHost w/ Apache for my Icinga instance. Icinga is up and running and I can access it from x.x.x.x/icinga, however would like to be able to access it externally as well as internally.

I have set up the /etc/hosts file and the following is my barebones vhost statement in httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/icinga
    ServerName icinga.domain.com
    ErrorLog logs/icinga.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

I also have the following in my `.htaccess` file

```
<Directory>
        Allow From All
        Satisfy Any
</Directory>
```

An entry has been made for the instance in the Windows DNS server on my network, however when I try to access the site by URL I am greeted with Internal Server Error.

Reviewing the /var/log/icinga.com-error_log I see the following entry.

```
[Thu Dec 13 16:04:39 2012] [alert] [client 10.0.0.1] /usr/share/icinga/.htaccess: <Directory not allowed here
```

Can someone help me spot the error of my ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `<Directory>` stuff in the `.htaccess` file.

Apache knows to what directory it applies to - hence, it's the directory the `.htaccess` file is in! You can't override configuration of other directories in `.htaccess` files (security feature). Besides, your `<Directory>` start tag misses the directory itself if you would put it in the main configuration; it should be e.g. `<Directory /path/to/dir>`.

Answer (score 2):

Apache is telling you exactly what's wrong: `<Directory>` is not allowed `here` (in your .htaccess file).

If you look at [the Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory) you'll see that `<Directory>` is only allowed in two contexts: **server config** and **virtual host**.

(The contents of a `.htaccess` file are implicitly applied to the filesystem directory  containing it, so you don't need the `<Directory>` directive.)

---

You will also find [a tutorial on how to write `.htaccess` files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) in the Apache documentation which may be helpful.